# need help to solve the syntax error message

Tags: python

```
else Moves=='x':
              t.up()
              t.goto(220,200)
              t.down()
              t.setheading(45)
              t.fd(length)
              t.bk(length)
              t.fd(length/2)
              t.setheading(135)
              t.fd(length/2)
              t.bk(length)
              t.up()
              t.fd(length/2)
```

When i run the program it says syntax error and Moves highlighted in red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Else* in python or any language doesnot accept a condition. The construct you want to use if you want to put a condition after *if* is

> elif

so your construct should be

```
elif Moves=='x':
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what your conditional flow looks like, but it looks like it should be elif instead of else

```
elif Moves=='x':
```

Expressions follow if and elif statements.